# How to flashlight turn off or on in background mode

Tags: ios

Please let me know how to flashlight run in background mode. When flash light ON with button after application enter in background mode how to turn on app continue.

Comment: So when the app goes into background mode you want to turn the light off?

Comment: Hi,i first turn on flashlight after some time app go to background  mode then i want to continue run it background mode.